# on POST back wont create new record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

Using MVC Orchard services file to allow the user to enter a new record in the 'HoursWorkedToday' table, allowing the user to enter how many hours they have worked that day.

```
//HoursWorkedService
public class HoursWorkedService : IHoursWorkedService
    {
        private IRepository<HoursWorkedPerDay> _repository = null;

        public HoursWorkedService(IRepository<HoursWorkedPerDay> Repository)
        {
            _repository = Repository;
        }

        public Models.HoursWorkedPerDay Create(HoursWorkedPerDay newRecordForHoursWorked)
        {
            _repository.Create(newRecordForHoursWorked);

            return newRecordForHoursWorked;
        }

//IHoursWorkedService
 public interface IHoursWorkedService : IDependency
    {
        HoursWorkedPerDay Create(HoursWorkedPerDay newRecordForHoursWorked);
    }

//controller
[HttpPost, ActionName("HoursWorkedPerDay")]
        public ActionResult HoursWorkedPerDayPOST(int userId, int hours)
        {  
            DateTime TodaysDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

            HoursWorkedPerDay HoursPerDay = new HoursWorkedPerDay();
            HoursPerDay.Date = TodaysDate;
            HoursPerDay.WorkerRecord_Id = userId;
            HoursPerDay.HoursWorked = hours;

            _hoursWorked.Create(HoursPerDay);

            _notifier.Add(NotifyType.Information, T("Thank you, Hours Added."));

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

but after the post i get the 'website can not display'

LOGS show:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'Orchard.Timekeeper.dbo.Timekeeper_HoursWorkedPerDay'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

In my migration file i have 'id' set to .ContentPartRecord(), which i assumed created the next record automatically when the service was used

Comment: Can you post the relevant migration?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ContentPartRecord on something that is not a content part record. Instead, add the Id column yourself as identity so that it gets auto-incremented.
If it is meant as a content part record, never use it without a content item. In particular, never use the repository directly on part records, and go through the content manager instead.